# 100% height button/label/input in a table cell iOS safari

Tags: ios, css, safari

I can't find a way to do this

There seems to be padding placed above and below the element, although I have set it zero

https://plnkr.co/edit/WvEqNCxEcLY5yS1IT738?p=preview

```
<div>
   <button>hello</button>
</div>

<table><tr><td>
   <button>hiya</button>
</td></tr></table>

td,
div{
  padding: 0;
  height: 10em;
  border: solid;
}

button {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  border:solid 10px #f00;
}
```

I don't want to use absolute position as the contents vary, and JS would be an overhead I couldn't live with!

Is there a known bug here? Would anyone have a link to it so I can watch it not get fixed for years and drives me to a stress related end

Thanks in advance

ios pic

[image]

chrome on win 10 (desired result)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The`button, input, textarea, img, video, audio` etc. are REPLACED ELEMENTS. The positioning rules for them are other than for standard elements. You can try to enclose replaced elements into a span or div.

Add `<div/>` inside `<td/>` and put `<button/>` into `<div/>` it will work properly. Add styles to new `<div/>` element and use:

```
button 
{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

<table><tr><td><div class="replaced-element-container"><button>hiya</button></div></td></tr></table>
```

Well, this is embarrassing but it meets W3C requirements.

Comment: Ha! I suddenly feel I can live with a JS fix - do you know if anything be done with ::before or ::after to avoid markup changes?

Comment: I suggest do not use JS fix. button with 100% height can be shown dirrefently in other browsers. JS fix: avoid of button and use... role="button". Why you use button? you can use `<a role="button" onclick="your javascript"></a>` instead of button. `href` is optional.

Comment: the button is because it's doing an action - not linking. but anyway other elements, such as input do this too, and make my grid look poo in iOS. A markup fix would hit the other browsers unnecessarily, with JS I can detect iOS and wrap the element as you suggest

Comment: <button type="submit"></button>?

Comment: I tested on chrome (-: The same behaviour. Do not detect Safari in the case.

Comment: chrome on iOS? isnt that using the same webkit engine? I'd detect iOS not the browser.
chrome looks fine on my desktop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152304/discussion-between-anthony-johnston-and-18c).

Comment: No Chrome on Windows. I never longer name "Chrome" for CriOS. CriOS and "firefox for iOS" (shall be named "FriOS") and Safari is the same product. Apple doesn't LIKE GECKO and doesn't like Blink. These render engines are forbidden by Apple.

Comment: aye, odd ms got done for IE on windows - dunno how they get away with it - but hey - I uploaded what I am seeing on Chrome on Windows - also looks fine on Android - its just iOS thats not right

Comment: test on Chromium 55 for Windows. Additional padding visible on my computer.

Comment: Look at my second answer if you don't want to wrap replaced elements (input, button etc.) into `<div/>`. I know it is not kosher and I also don't like div-itis but replaced elements has other positioning rules described by W3C documents... left+right with position absolute also doesn't work like you want.

Comment: Remember - you also cannot use `::after` and `::before` on replaced elements (including `<br/>`, `<hr/>` and `<img/>`). It may work on part of browsers but this is not a requirement due to W3C documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For one table cell in the row:

```
td,  div
{
   padding: 0;
   height: 10em;
   border: solid;
   display:block;
}

button 
{
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   border:solid 10px #f00;
}
```

But it doesn't resolve problem that button is replaced element. It is still in container made from `<td/>` element.